# Asynchronously Load Image Thumbnails Android

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

**What I Have**

I have a AsyncTask to generate the thumbnails and attach them to the ImageView.

```
public class ThumbnailTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference imageViewReference;

    public ThumbnailTask(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        return decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(params[0], 115, 90);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                else {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(imageView.getContext().getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.thumb3));
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Now I call the execute method like this,

```
if(holder.fileImage != null){
                    new ThumbnailTask(holder.fileImage).execute(o.getFilePath());
                }
```

**My Problem**

The main problem that I have is that, when I scroll down the list, wrong thumbnals get attached to the image views. It takes some time after which the correct images get attached again to the thumbnails.

Can anyone help me out with this, so that the correct thumbnail gets attached to the correct item?

Comment: for best dealing with image loading try universal image loader or aQuery library.

Comment: just think ... 1. ListView is reusing items ... 2. you started to download fx image from first item 3. now you scrolled down ListView in the way that 1st element is no longer visible ... 4.ListView reuse the view but you **did not stopped** old download request and started new one for this ImageView 5. Old request finished and shows wrong image ...

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing to remember is that the Layout used by a ListView is recycled. While I don't know your exact implementation, I'd venture to guess the problem is that:

1. at first you have `ThumbnailTask[img1]` associated to a particular `ImageView`
2. The list is scrolled, so a `ThumbnailTask[img11]` may now also be associated to the same `ImageView` without `ThumbnailTask[img1]`'s knowledge.
3. When `ThumbnailTask[img1]` finishes it will update `ImageView`,
4. After a while `ThumbnailTask[img11]` would finish and update the same `ImageView`.

To properly asynchronously loading and displaying stuff is a non-trivial problem, I'd suggest you to try any of the following libraries to get it done right for you:

1. [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
2. [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
3. [ion](https://github.com/koush/ion)

Answer (score 0):

See http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html for a detailed discussion about how to properly load bitmaps asynchronously in a list or grid if you don't want to use a third-party framework to do it for you (since as Kai mentioned, it's a non-trivial problem to get it right).

from the link:

```
public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView imageView) {
    if (cancelPotentialWork(resId, imageView)) {
        final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView);
        final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable =
                new AsyncDrawable(getResources(), mPlaceHolderBitmap, task);
        imageView.setImageDrawable(asyncDrawable);
        task.execute(resId);
    }
}

static class AsyncDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    private final WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask> bitmapWorkerTaskReference;

    public AsyncDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap,
            BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask) {
        super(res, bitmap);
        bitmapWorkerTaskReference =
            new WeakReference<BitmapWorkerTask>(bitmapWorkerTask);
    }

    public BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask() {
        return bitmapWorkerTaskReference.get();
    }
}

public static boolean cancelPotentialWork(int data, ImageView imageView) {
    final BitmapWorkerTask bitmapWorkerTask = getBitmapWorkerTask(imageView);

    if (bitmapWorkerTask != null) {
        final int bitmapData = bitmapWorkerTask.data;
        if (bitmapData != data) {
            // Cancel previous task
            bitmapWorkerTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            // The same work is already in progress
            return false;
        }
    }
    // No task associated with the ImageView, or an existing task was cancelled
    return true;
}

private static BitmapWorkerTask getBitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
   if (imageView != null) {
       final Drawable drawable = imageView.getDrawable();
       if (drawable instanceof AsyncDrawable) {
           final AsyncDrawable asyncDrawable = (AsyncDrawable) drawable;
           return asyncDrawable.getBitmapWorkerTask();
       }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The key piece you may be missing is canceling a previous task before starting a new one, which would explain why the previous image is loading in it's place.